# Sue and Freddie: The Dynamic Mystery Duo - The Trouble with Sue's Hair

Tags: particles, hair

Once again, I am a 3D modeler who is starting to know how to use Blender, and in addition, I also have another question.

Here is the trouble with Sue's hair in which I used the hair modifier simulation.

[image: Here is the trouble with Sue's hair.]

The first frame at the very beginning should show what Sue's hair should actually look like.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v46Y9_EBKCk

Is it possible to stabilize the hair?  Has anyone else using Blender experienced the same problem with hair simulation?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you applied all the scales and locations to your mesh? This looks like bad collisions to me.

Comment: Hi there.  It's been a year.  I have just applied all the scales and locations to my mesh.  although it looked a bit better than the previous picture I posted earlier, it still suffers the same flailing problem.